# Show that for all $n$, If $n$ is a multiple of $58$, then $n+7$ and $n^{2}+9$ are coprime.

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, coprime

How do I approach this question? I am unsure of how to use Euclid's algorithm and simultaneously incorporate that $n$ is a multiple of $58$. Thanks!

Comment: $gcd(n+7, n^{2}+9) = gcd(n+7, 58).$

Comment: Could you please clarify a little as I am confused about how to attain a gcd of 1 when there is a pronumeral involved. Thanks

Comment: Helps to note that, for all $n$, $(n+7)\,|\,(n^2-49)$.

Comment: For what it's worth, I posted an answer and then deleted it, because my answer confused $(n+9)^2$ with $n^2 + 9.$

Comment: $$n^2+9 = (n+7)^2 - 14(n+7) + 58 \, ,$$ so if $d>1$ divides both of your numbers at the same time, it also divides $58$. Hence, $d=2,29,58$. However, any of these divide $n$, but not $7$ or $9$.

Comment: written as a step in the Euclidean algorithm,  $$  \left(   x^{2}  + 9 \right)  =  \left(   x  + 7 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 7 \right) } +  \left( 58  \right)  $$

Answer (score 1):

If not then there exists a common divisor **d > 1**. It must also divide  **n^2+9 - n(n+7) = 9-7n**. Likewise **d** is a divisor of **9-7n + 7(n+7) = 58**. So **58** is GCD of **n^2+9** and **n+7**.

But if **n = 58m** then **58m+7** cannot be a multiple of 58.